# React query ssr TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON

Tags: javascript, reactjs, server-side-rendering, circular-dependency, react-query

I'm following the react-query ssr documentation but I'm getting an error. What am I doing wrong?
I know what is circular structure. but in the documentation everything works fine

https://tanstack.com/query/v4/docs/guides/ssr

[Error text and code example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dPYzj.png)

Comment: Instead of an image, you could've c/p your code here on SO. It would be much more readable that way. It seems to me like you're getting that error because you're trying to `JSON.stringify(dehydratedState)`. Try removing that line and see if it will work. And if you want to `console.log` it, just remove `JSON.stringify`

Comment: please put the code and error directly into the question, not on externally hosted environments as an image!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are returning everything that `axios` gives you from the queryFn. axios responses contain lots of meta data that are a) not json serializable and b) you likely don't want to include. The whole RequestConfig is included in the response, which is where the error is coming from.

What you want is to only extract the `.data` property from axios and return that, because that's the json response:

```
await queryClient.prefetchQuery(
  ['todos'],
  () => axios.get(url).then(response => response.data)
```

Comment: Thank you! May bad, it was so stupid error.